# Modify a variable in remote bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ssh, sed

I want to modify an existing variable on a remote machine. On a local machine I use 'sed' for that. But how can I achieve this on a remote machine?

comlink.sh:
The remote file containing the variable that should be changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
test=1
new=2
ready=0
```

How I change that variable locally:

```
sed 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' /home/pi/comlink.sh > tmp
mv tmp /home/pi/comlink.sh
```

My approach of what I want to achieve remotely:

```html
sed 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' ssh pi@[myIP] /home/pi/comlink.sh > tmp
mv ssh pi@[myIP] tmp /home/pi/comlink.sh
```

But this is not the right way or syntax. I think I might need some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to do it that way at all, rather than to pass the value you want over your SSH command? So, `ssh pi@"$yourIP" "env ready=1 /home/pi/comlink.sh"`, after modifying your script to accept any value it inherits (ie. `: "${ready:=0}"` instead of `ready=0`)

Comment: Or `ready=$1` in the script, and `ssh pi@yourHost "comlink.sh 1"` to read it.

Comment: Which is to say: Best practice is to keep code and data separate, and thus to avoid trying to put data in your code (and then need to automate editing that code) in the first place. This makes it easier to use proper revision control systems (you can copy code around without unintentional diffs from data changes), and makes it easier to create and enforce good security policy (like marking your code read-only while your data is read-write).

Comment: If you did     **sed -i 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' /home/pi/comlink.sh** you can skip  creating the temporary file and automatically write over the comlink.sh file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this: it's really just a quoting challenge -- execute the sed command remotely

```
ssh pi@ip "sed -i 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' /home/pi/comlink.sh"
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first word in a Bash expression is a command (a program, alias, function, builtin, etc.). `ssh` is a program to connect to remote machines, so you can't just drop the string "ssh" into other commands and have *them* do the work of `ssh`. The confusion is understandable because the opposite *is* somewhat true - you can pass arbitrary commands to `ssh` in order to execute them on the remote machine.

So while `sed PATTERN ssh pi@[myIP] ...` is meaningless (you're applying `PATTERN` to files in your current directory called `ssh` and `pi@[myIP]`, which presumably don't exist), you *can* say something like:

```
ssh pi@[myIP] "cat /home/pi/comlink.sh"
```

To output the contents of a file on your remote machine named `/home/pi/comlink.sh`.

You can also do more complex operations, like output redirection (`>`), over `ssh`, but you need to ensure the full command you want to run is being passed to `ssh` by quoting it - otherwise the output redirection will occur locally. Compare:

```
ssh pi@[myIP] echo foo > /tmp/foo
```

vs.

```
ssh pi@[myIP] 'echo foo > /tmp/foo'
```

The former will invoke `echo foo` on your remote machine and write the output to `/tmp/foo` on your *local* machine. The latter will invoke `echo foo > /tmp/foo` on the remote machine.

Take a look also at the [`-i` flag for `sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) - it will apply the pattern in-place to the given file(s), so you don't need to write to a temporary file and then move it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Complicated stuff for a beginner. But I was heading in the right direction at least!